# What is the cost of access to a configuration property?

Tags: performance, scala, playframework

I'm developing a Scala app that scan some folders in a interval of 10 minutes. Inside my class, I've created like 12 global variable and it's kinda strange because some variables are used only one time on exception point.

I was wondering what is the cost of use:

> configuration.getString("value")

Every time instead create a global variable like:

> private lazy val inputPath = configuration.getString("main.directory")

In terms of performance, what is better? Call only when it's necessary or create a lazy global variable?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`configuration.getString("value")` is very cheap. The config will be read and parsed once at startup and then the values are stored in a java `Map`. So basically calling `getString` boils down to a lookup in a `HashMap`. That is of course more expensive than a shared variable but is still of constant complexity O(1). It should be fine especially when you call `getString` only a couple of times every 10 minutes.

The implementation im referring to can be found in the [sources of typesafe/config on GitHub](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/99afd721a557b36b5b9eadad7406be3c1383228a/config/src/main/java/com/typesafe/config/impl/SimpleConfigObject.java#L30). Line 30 is the map in which the values are stored.

---

**Update**: Your question came to my mind this morning and it suddenly struck me why it is a bad idea after all to call `getString` instead of initializing a shared variable with the value. It didn't come to my mind immediately because it has nothing to do with performance:

`getString` has side effects namely it can throw an exception when the config value is not present - your config file might be corrupted for instance. Since there usually is no recovery strategy for this kind of exception, it would be much better practice to have these potential failures at startup instead of a couple of tens of minutes into the program when nobody is watching anymore.

In your question you used a `lazy val` as an alternative which would be exposed to the very same problem, since it would only be evaluated when needed. So in my opinion you should read all config values into `val`s at the beginning of the program!

```
private val inputPath = configuration.getString("main.directory")
```

This does of course not apply if you use fallback values and are 100% positive that there will be no exceptions.

Comment: "It should be fine especially when you call `getString` only a couple of times every 10 minutes." I'd say "It should be fine especially since you're _doing I/O to scan directories_."

Comment: Yes, i only get the directory path and replace a part to find the client dir..it's a simple operation.